# Как запретить использовать неверно инициализированный объект в java

Tags: java

Допустим, есть такие классы:

```
class Parent {
    int p1, p2;
    public Parent(int p1, int p2){
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }

    public void printVars(){
        System.out.printf("%d %d", p1, p2);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    public Child(int p1, int p2){
        super(p1, p2);
    }
}
```

Но мне нужно, чтобы в случаях, когда `p1 > p2` нельзя было пользоваться созданным объектом класса  `Child`.
Т.е. при попытке сделать так:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Child child = new Child(2, 1);
        child.printVars();
    }
}
```

выдать ошибку, например.
Как это сделать ?

Comment: в конструкторе написать проверку if (p1 > p2) {thow exeption}

Comment: @стасевич если написать после `supe()`, то объектом можно пользоваться. если перед - `java: call to super must be first statement in constructor` во время сборки приложения.

Comment: @n1tr0xs, объект `Child` не будет создан, если будет выброшено исключение, однако такой дизайн по всей видимости нарушает принцип Лисков -- объекты `Child` не могут всегда замещать объекты родительского класса `Parent`

Answer (score 2):

Обычно в таких случаях добавляют проверку в конструктор класса:

```java
class Child extends Parent {
        public Child(int p1, int p2) {
            super(p1, p2);
            if(p1 > p2)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("p1 was greater than p2");
        }
    }
```

Comment: при таком  коде мне `java` говорит: `java: call to super must be first statement in constructor`

Comment: @n1tr0xs вызов super всегда должен быть первым вызовом в конструкторе, поставь super перед if

Comment: и если вызывается родительский конструктор, нужно проверку туда вносить, а у наследников просто вызывать super.

Comment: @n1tr0xs тут момент, если все производные от parent и класс родителя нужно ограничить, то надо прописывать в конструкторе родителя, если отдельного наследника, то в классе наследника